# Tricky C function testing knowledge static, global, local variables and pointers

Tags: c, pointers

Disclaimer: Yes this is a homework problem. I'm having a particularly difficult time understanding what the function f2 does.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int i = 10; /* global variable */
int j = 1; /* global variable */
/* Forward function declarations */
void swap(int, int); int f1(int);
void f2(int, int *);

int main()
{
    {
        int i = 1;
        int j = 10;
        swap(i,j); printf("i = %d j = %d\n", i,j);
        j = f1(i++); printf("i = %d j = %d\n", i,j);
        f2(f1(i),&j); printf("i = %d j = %d\n", i,j);
        //which j does this refer to? The static variable, global, or local and why
    }
    j = f1(i/2); printf("i = %d j = %d\n", i,j);
    f2(f1(i),&j); printf("i = %d j = %d\n", i,j);
    return 0;
}
void swap(int a, int b)
{
    int temp;
    temp=b; b=a; a=temp;
}
int f1(int x)
{
    static int j = 5;
    i++;
    j+=x;
    return j;
}
void f2(int x, int *p)
{
    *p+=x;
    *p = (*p>20) ? 20 :*p++;
}
```

When I run this code into the compiler, I get the following answer:

```
i = 1 j = 10
i = 2 j = 6
i = 14 j = 14
i = 13 j = 14
i = 14 j = 20
```

I understand the first set of i and j, the reason being swap does nothing because the variables a and b are deleted in the heap.

For the second set, we increment the i in main and then we use the value 1 as x because i++ is post-increment. We create a static variable j, the global variable x gets increased to 11, and it returns j as 6 because x is added to j. After the function is completed, the i variable in the main gets incremented to 2. This leads to 2 and 6.

For the third print statement, I first call f1(i) which is equal to two, this resets j to 5 and increments the global variable i to 12. Then j gets set to 7 and we return 7 for f1(i). Then this is the part I am having difficulty on. We then pass the memory location of j as the parameter, but which j do we pass and why? From the output it seems as if the static j's memory is being passed but I'm not sure.

As we go into the function f2, we get *p+=x, which I believe gives the value 14 because x is set to 7 from earlier and j is also 7. What I do not get is the second line: "*p = (*p>20) ? 20 :*p++;". What does this even mean? From the output it seems to have copied the value of j into i.

What does the second line of code in the function f2 do and which j (the bolded one with a & sign in front of it) is called in the line "f2(f1(i),&**j**); printf("i = %d j = %d\n", i,j);".

Comment: You should use a debugger to step through the code line by line and inspect what each line does (and what values the variables have) - also your analysis of what happens is wrong, just before you step into `f2` your print says that `i = 13 j = 14`, so why do you think `*p+=x;` yields 14?

Comment: I haven't gotten to that portion yet. There are a total of 5 times where i and j are printed. There line "j = f1(i/2); printf("i = %d j = %d\n", i,j);" is called twice, once in a curly brace and once without. I'm still on the first call which correlates with the third pair, which does in fact give the output 14 14. The pair you are referring to is the 4th pair and I have not gotten there yet.

Comment: There is no heap allocation in your program, since it does not use malloc/free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instructions of `f2` do the following:

```
*p+=x;
```

This adds the value of `x` to whatever is stored at the location pointed to by `p`. The `*` dereferences pointer `p`.

```
*p = (*p>20) ? 20 :*p++;
```

If the value stored at `p` is larger than 20, then store 20 at `p`. Otherwise store the value of `p` at `p` and increment `p`, which is undefined behavior (pointed out by Cool Guy), as `*p++` is equivalent to `*p = *p; p++;`

Comment: Thank you, that was very informative. Do you know which j is called on the line before I added a comment in my question? Or to rephrase it in a slightly easier way, could you answer the // comment located in my question above that I just added?

Comment: In `f2(f1(i),&j);` the inner `j` is used. The outer `j` is no longer visible with a nearer declaration of another `j`. in `f1` the local, static `j` is used. The gobal `j` is also not visible anymore with a nearer `j` declared. This concept is called "scope".

Comment: "_Otherwise just increment the value stored at `p`_" - Isn't it UB to do `*p = *p++;`?